# ASP.NET MVC: how to monitor incomming request traffic to an MVC application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-services, monitoring

I have a MVC application which acts as a REST web-services for my android application. Android client application send some request to my MVC web-application. 
How can I see list and detail of requests received (POST/GET) reqeusts sent to my MVC application? This if for debugging purpose.

Comment: are you searching a builtin solution ? because you can also create yourself lib called in the BeginRequest

Comment: @GGO I was looking for some available software tool or a built-in solution

Comment: Yes, have you looked about ISS logs parsing ? i know logs parsers exist but i don't remember their names